# QBMS (Quickbooks Merchant Services) Scheduled Billing doesn't show up in Dashboard

Tags: recurring-billing, quickbooks-online

I have added a wallet and scheduled billing for the future, I receive the scheduled billing ID and a success message, but when I go to recurring payments (this is all in the sandbox -- ptc), I don't see anything.

This is my request:

```
POST https://webmerchantaccount.ptc.quickbooks.com/j/AppGateway HTTP/1.1

Content-Type: application/x-qbmsxml
Content-Length: 770

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbmsxml version="4.5"?>
<QBMSXML>
    <SignonMsgsRq>
        <SignonTicketRq>
            <ClientDateTime>2012-01-30T17:03:42</ClientDateTime>
            <SessionTicket>***********************</SessionTicket>
        </SignonTicketRq>
    </SignonMsgsRq>
    <QBMSXMLMsgsRq>
        <CustomerScheduledBillingAddRq>
            <CustomerID>1234721</CustomerID>
            <WalletEntryID>102142113311000320665100</WalletEntryID>
            <PaymentType>CreditCard</PaymentType>
            <Amount>1.06</Amount>
            <SalesTaxAmount>0.06</SalesTaxAmount>
            <StartDate>2012-01-31</StartDate>
            <FrequencyExpression>0 0 0 1 * ?</FrequencyExpression>
            <ScheduledBillingStatus>Active</ScheduledBillingStatus>
        </CustomerScheduledBillingAddRq>
    </QBMSXMLMsgsRq>
</QBMSXML>
```

Then I get this response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE QBMSXML PUBLIC "-//INTUIT//DTD QBMSXML QBMS 4.5//EN" "http://webmerchantaccount.ptc.quickbooks.com/dtds/qbmsxml45.dtd">
<QBMSXML>
 <SignonMsgsRs>
  <SignonTicketRs statusCode="0" statusSeverity="INFO">
   <ServerDateTime>2012-01-30T23:07:46</ServerDateTime>
   <SessionTicket>***********************</SessionTicket>
  </SignonTicketRs>
 </SignonMsgsRs>
 <QBMSXMLMsgsRs>
  <CustomerScheduledBillingAddRs statusCode="0" statusMessage="Status OK" statusSeverity="INFO">
   <ScheduledBillingID>5225</ScheduledBillingID>
  </CustomerScheduledBillingAddRs>
 </QBMSXMLMsgsRs>
</QBMSXML>
```

---

Can anyone tell me why I can't see this in the dashboard? Or where I should see it?

Thanks!

Comment: on a related note , how do i know that the payment of the next month is received once i have created scheduled billing ?, i have done same as Kerry,and i have got a Scheduled billing id. i have implemented it in PRODUCTION , but how will i know if the customers payment has been done[apart from dashboard].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a TEST/PTC merchant account, the transactions won't show up in the GUI dashboard. That's just how Intuit's system works. :-(